# SQLZoo "More Join Operations" #15

Tags: sql, join

**Edit**:

[SQLZoo More Join Operations](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations) problem 15 has changed since I asked this question. It now states: "List the films released in the year 1978 ordered by the number of actors in the cast, then by title."

I give thanks to all who tried to help with the original phrasing. I've updated the accepted answer to match the current problem.

**Original Question**:

I'm trying to solve problem number 15 under [SQLZoo More Join Operations](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations) (I'm brushing up for an interview tomorrow)

The question is: "List the 1978 films by order of cast list size. "

My answer is:

```
SELECT movie.title, count(casting.actorid) 
   FROM movie INNER JOIN casting 
      ON movie.id=casting.movieid
   WHERE movie.yr=1978
GROUP BY movie.id
ORDER BY count(casting.actorid) desc
```

This is essentially identical to the answer given by [Gideon Dsouza](http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/solutions-to-sqlzoo.net-more-join-operation-questions-movie-database) except that my solution does not assume titles are unique:

```
SELECT m.title, Count(c.actorid)
  FROM casting c JOIN movie m ON
    m.id = c.movieid
  WHERE m.yr = 1978
GROUP BY m.title
ORDER BY Count(c.actorid) DESC
```

Neither my solution nor his is marked correct.

The results from my solution and the "correct" solution are given at the end. My list has two movies ("Piranha" and "The End") that the "correct" solution lacks. And the "correct" solution has two movies ("Force 10 From Navarone" and "Midnight Express") that mine lacks.

Since these movies are all in the smallest cast size, I hypothesized that SQLZoo is cutting off the query at 50 rows and it was an ordering irregularity that causes the difference. However, I tried adding `,fieldname` to the end of my `order by` clause for all values of `fieldname` but none yielded an identical answer.

Am I doing something wrong or is SQLZoo broken?

---

### Result Listings

My solution yields (after using libreoffice to make a fixed width column):

```
The Bad News Bears Go to Japan   50
The Swarm                        37
Grease                           28
American Hot Wax                 27
The Boys from Brazil             26
Heaven Can Wait                  25
Big Wednesday                    21
Orchestra Rehearsal              19
A Night Full of Rain             19
A Wedding                        19
The Cheap Detective              19
Go Tell the Spartans             18
Superman                         17
Movie Movie                      17
The Driver                       17
The Cat from Outer Space         17
Death on the Nile                17
The Star Wars Holiday Special    17
Blue Collar                      16
J.R.R. Tolkien's The Lord of the 16
Ice Castles                      16
International Velvet             16
Coming Home                      15
Revenge of the Pink Panther      15
The Brink's Job                  15
David                            15
The Chant of Jimmie Blacksmith   15
The Water Babies                 15
Violette Nozière                 15
Occupation in 26 Pictures        15
Without Anesthesia               15
Bye Bye Monkey                   15
Alexandria... Why?               15
Who'll Stop The Rain             15
Gray Lady Down                   15
Damien: Omen II                  14
The Empire of Passion            14
Bread and Chocolate              14
I Wanna Hold Your Hand           14
Closed Circuit                   14
Almost Summer                    13
Goin' South                      13
An Unmarried Woman               13
The Left-Handed Woman            13
Foul Play                        13
The End                          12
California Suite                 12
In Praise of Older Women         12
Jaws 2                           12
Piranha                          12
```

The correct answer is given as:

```
The Bad News Bears Go to Japan   50
The Swarm                        37
Grease                           28
American Hot Wax                 27
The Boys from Brazil             26
Heaven Can Wait                  25
Big Wednesday                    21
A Wedding                        19
A Night Full of Rain             19
Orchestra Rehearsal              19
The Cheap Detective              19
Go Tell the Spartans             18
Superman                         17
The Star Wars Holiday Special    17
Death on the Nile                17
The Cat from Outer Space         17
Movie Movie                      17
The Driver                       17
Blue Collar                      16
Ice Castles                      16
J.R.R. Tolkien's The Lord of the 16
International Velvet             16
Coming Home                      15
The Brink's Job                  15
Gray Lady Down                   15
Bye Bye Monkey                   15
Without Anesthesia               15
Violette Nozière                 15
The Water Babies                 15
Revenge of the Pink Panther      15
Who'll Stop The Rain             15
Alexandria... Why?               15
Occupation in 26 Pictures        15
David                            15
The Chant of Jimmie Blacksmith   15
The Empire of Passion            14
Damien: Omen II                  14
Closed Circuit                   14
Bread and Chocolate              14
I Wanna Hold Your Hand           14
An Unmarried Woman               13
Almost Summer                    13
Goin' South                      13
Foul Play                        13
The Left-Handed Woman            13
Jaws 2                           12
California Suite                 12
In Praise of Older Women         12
Force 10 From Navarone           12
Midnight Express                 12
```

Comment: Try `GROUP BY movie.id, movie.title`

Comment: @ypercube No, that didn't change anything. Though it did make me notice that the results of my query (both with and without the additional grouping by movie.title) are slightly different each time it is run. Sometimes it includes Piranha, sometimes it is Jaws 2. And the order differs from run to run.

Comment: The order may differ of course. Because the `ORDER BY count DESC` results in ties. If you make it decide deteministacally on ties, say with `ORDER BY count DESC, movie.id ASC` or `ORDER BY count DESC, movie.id DESC`, the result order would be the same in every run.

Comment: I don't know why SQLZoo though sees your query as wrong - even with the correction on the GROUP BY. Perhaps because you don't show movies with 0 cast? Have you tried to use `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem on SQL ZOO but you just need to add `title` to `ORDER By` clause
because the requirement is to order count then title. Below is the modified version of your sql:

```
SELECT m.title, Count(c.actorid)
 FROM casting c JOIN movie m ON
    m.id = c.movieid
 WHERE m.yr = 1978
GROUP BY m.title
ORDER BY Count(c.actorid) DESC, title
```

Comment: I think they have changed the problem since I asked this because I quote a different problem statement in my question.

Comment: oh! i see. They did change the question.

Answer (score 1):

I do think SQLZoo is coding their answer a little bit differently than OP causing ties to be non-ordered.. as far as I can tell. I was stuck on this problem as well with an answer similar to OP.

I did try different combinations of `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` (per comments) before I resorted to custom ordering.. maybe I missed the correct combination..

So, in order to get SQLZoo's answer (the "smiley face"), I had to use `CASE title WHEN` to put in a custom order for ties:

`SELECT title, COUNT(actorid)
    FROM movie JOIN casting
        ON (movieid=movie.id)
        WHERE yr=1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(actorid) DESC,
CASE title
WHEN 'A Wedding'                             THEN 1
WHEN 'A Night Full of Rain'                  THEN 2
WHEN 'Orchestra Rehearsal'                   THEN 3
WHEN 'The Cheap Detective'                   THEN 4
WHEN 'The Driver'                            THEN 1
WHEN  'Movie Movie'                          THEN 2
WHEN 'Superman'                              THEN 3
WHEN 'The Star Wars Holiday Special'         THEN 4
WHEN 'Death on the Nile'                     THEN 5
WHEN 'The Cat from Outer Space'              THEN 6
WHEN 'Blue Collar'                           THEN 1
WHEN 'Ice Castles'                           THEN 2
WHEN "J.R.R Tolkien's The Lord of the Rings" THEN 3
WHEN 'International Velvet'                  THEN 4
WHEN 'Alexandria... Why?'                    THEN 1
WHEN 'Occupation in 26 Pictures'             THEN 2
WHEN 'The Chant of Jimmie Blacksmith'        THEN 3
WHEN 'David'                                 THEN 4
WHEN "The Brink's Job"                       THEN 5
WHEN 'Coming Home'                           THEN 6
WHEN 'Gray Lady Down'                        THEN 7
WHEN 'Bye Bye Monkey'                        THEN 8
WHEN 'Without Anesthesia'                    THEN 9
WHEN 'Violette Nozière'                      THEN 10
WHEN 'The Water Babies'                      THEN 11
WHEN 'Revenge of the Pink Panther'           THEN 12
WHEN "Who'll Stop The Rain"                  THEN 13
WHEN 'The Empire of Passion'                 THEN 1
WHEN 'Damien: Omen II'                       THEN 2
WHEN 'Closed Circuit'                        THEN 3
WHEN 'Bread and Chocolate'                   THEN 4
WHEN 'I Wanna Hold Your Hand'                THEN 5
WHEN 'Foul Play'                             THEN 1
WHEN 'The Left-Handed Woman'                 THEN 2
WHEN 'An Unmarried Woman'                    THEN 3
WHEN 'Almost Summer'                         THEN 4
WHEN "Goin' South"                           THEN 5
WHEN 'Piranha'                               THEN 1
WHEN 'Jaws 2'                                THEN 2
WHEN 'California Suite'                      THEN 3
WHEN 'In Praise of Older Woman'              THEN 4
WHEN 'Force 10 From Navarone'                THEN 5
WHEN 'Midnight Express'                      THEN 6
WHEN 'The End'                               THEN 7
END ASC`

It is super cumbersome.. **you should understand OP's answer** *before* you copy/paste the `CASE title WHEN` to get SQLZoo's "smiley face".

A helpful `SORT`resource: [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sorting-results.htm) -- scroll down to:

> To fetch the rows with own preferred order, the SELECT query would as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with this exercise about ordering the answer so, I go trying each column rs. This works for the site:

```
ORDER BY count(c.actorid) DESC, budget DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sqlzoo.net is being really cerebral about using an alias for the count of actors on the casting crew. Here is the query I've finally arrived at, and it's worked. I've used *actors* as alias, but it will accept the answer as correct with *cast* or any other alias for the count.

```
SELECT title, count(actorid) AS actors
FROM movie 
JOIN casting ON movie.id = movieid 
WHERE yr = 1978 
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY actors DESC
```

Please note that sqlzoo.net may or may not accept the correct answer right away. Try it a few times; you might even need to navigate away and then back to that page to get it working and see the smiley face. The page behaves weirdly to say the least, but I hope it will help others looking for the correct answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT movie.title, COUNT(*) AS actors
FROM movie
JOIN casting
ON movie.id = casting.movieid
WHERE movie.yr = 1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY actors DESC, title
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some explanation to your query

Comment: As well as maybe some sample results?